# How to add pop up (ID and name) from list of users from Knockout js

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, popup, chat

**My pop up script looks like this**

```
function register_popup(id, name) {
        for (var iii = 0; iii < popups.length; iii++) {
            //already registered. Bring it to front.
            if (id == popups[iii]) {
                Array.remove(popups, iii);
                popups.unshift(id);
                calculate_popups();
                return;
            }
        }           
    }
```

**My html to list users looks like this**

```
<ul class="sidebar-name">
    <li data-bind="foreach: users">
        <a href="javascript:register_popup('qblock', data-bind=" text name");">
            <img width="30" height="30" src="my_images_path">
            <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
        </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

How can I add pop up (ID and name) from list of `users` from Knockout?

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using non-knockout script here and first, I would like to point out you shouldn't be doing this (not sure if you are rewriting a non-KO app into a KO one). If you use KO, you should utilize it and writing `href="javascript:..."` stuff is definitely not the way to do it. With that said, I'll outline the solution first.

You should create a viewmodel, which contains the list of users, and also maintains an object (or the index of it, that's also a possibility) which holds the currently visible conversation. As I understood your question, this is what you wanted to achieve.

So let's define a viewmodel like this:

```
function conversationViewModel(userId, userName, otherData) {
    var self = this;

    self.id = ko.observable(userId);
    self.name = ko.observable(userName);
    self.messages = ko.observableArray(null);

    // perform notification subscription here, implement 
    // logic to add the messages to self.messages

};

function chatViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.userList = ko.observableArray(null);
    self.selectedIndex = ko.observable(null);
    self.selectedConversation = ko.computed(function() {
        var idx = self.selectedIndex();

        // has value, but a value of 0 would result in false
        if (idx || idx == 0) {
            return self.userList()[idx];
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    });

    self.selectConversation = function(index) {
        self.selectedConversation(index);
    };

    self.refresh = function() {
        // pseudo-logic to load users and converstaion data
        var stuff = server.get();

        for (var i = 0; i < stuff.length; ++i) {
            stuff[i] = new conversationViewModel(stuff.id, stuff.name, stuff);
        }

        // populate the array of active conversations 
        // with data received from the server. Perform
        // any structural transformations here.
        userList(stuff);
    };
};

var chatVM = null;
$(function() {
    chatVM = new chatViewModel();

    ko.applyBindings(chatVM);
});
```

And then in your markup:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: userList">
    <li>
        <a data-bind="click: $parent.selectConversation.bind($data, $index)">
            <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>

<!-- ko if: !selectedConversation() -->
<div>
    Please select a user to view messages.
</div>
<!-- /ko -->

<!-- ko if: selectedConversation() -->
<div data-bind="with: selectedConversation">
    <h1>Conversation with <span data-bind="text: userName"></span></h1>

    <h2>Message history</h2>
    <ul data-bind="foreach: messages">
        <li>
            <!-- 
                here we assume each message object has a
                senderName and a messageText property
            -->
            <b data-bind="text: senderName"></b> said:
            <i data-bind="text: messageText"></i>
        </li>
    <ul>
</div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

**Let's see how it all works.**

We've defined two functions, the first is the 'constructor' of a conversation object. This holds the partner's name, the id, and the messages exchanged with that particular user. This is created so that for every new conversation we have a unified way of representing the data. For each conversation, we have to create a new object using this function. The third parameter passed to it is the data received from the server (for that particular converation), use this to extract any other neccessary data, such as the date of sending the message.

The second function is the constructor of the whole chat, which holds the conversations with all partners. This defines a `selectedIndex`, `selectedConversation` properties and a `selectConversation` function. The index holds the - well -, index of the currently visible conversation. The `selectedConversation` is simply a ko computed observable, which resolves the index to the appropriate array item. *Bind your conversation view to this object.* The `selectConversation` is simply a function which alters the value of the selected index. This is used to switch between conversations.

The markup is self explanatory: if there is a selected conversation, as per the value of the computed observable, we display the details of it. The fact that you display it as a popup or in an other column, does not matter as far as KO is concerned. You should implement **only one popup**, and bind data to display in it using knockout, instead of bringing them to the front and whatnot. If, on the other hand, there is no active conversation yet (either because there are no conversations at all or because none is selected yet), then we simply display a proper message telling the user to select something.